WebView2 send post request with JSON body
I have this code which works well with sending POST request using WebView2, but the problem is it sends body in Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded format. I need it as JSON.
Please suggest some ideas
var postScript = new StringBuilder(@$"var form = document.createElement('form'); form.method = 'POST'; form.action = '{parameters.Url}'; form.style.visibility = 'hidden';");

foreach (var field in parameters.PostData.Payload)
{
    postScript.Append(@$"var {field.Key}Field = document.createElement('input'); {field.Key}Field.name = '{field.Key}'; {field.Key}Field.value = '{field.Value}'; form.appendChild({field.Key}Field);");
}

postScript.Append("document.body.appendChild(form); form.submit();");

await webView.ExecuteScriptAsync(postScript.ToString());


It looks like you are simply creating and submitting a normal form there. You can not make a normal form submission send JSON.

Ehh, why do you ceate parameters on the server, then send them to the client, which posts them back to the server? (If you try some cross posting you will most likely run into CORS issues).
